# Using async pipe: Has any data loaded yet?

Tags: angular

I'm using the async pipe to load data returned from an Observable directly into my template.

```
public myData$ = Observable<DataResponse[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myData$ = this.myService.getData();
}
```

It loads just fine into my template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let data of dataStatus$ | async'>
```

But, i inherited a custom progress bar that shows until data is loaded via an attribute:

```
<my-progress-bar [showProgress]='???'
```

So, under the *showProgress* attribute I've got to determine when to shut off the progress bar. I know that all docs point to using the *;else #templateLiteral*. I've tried accessing the *complete* method of the Observable and also using

```
[showProgress]='dataStatus$'
```

...but that's not working either. Is there some property of the Observable I can use to pass into the progress component? Thanks for any helpful tips.

```
<my-progress-bar [showProgress]='???'>
    <table>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let data of dataStatus$ | async'>
            <tr *ngIf='!!data'>
                <td>/* all my stuff */</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
</my-progress-bar>
```

Comment: can u post your complete html file?

Comment: i've added the scaffolding at the bottom of the post. this should be all that's needed to provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a typical construction `<ng-container *ngIf="{data:(dataStatus$ | async) as dataStatus}>`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ data: (dataStatus$ | async) } as data">
  <div *ngIf="!data.data">loading...</div>
  <div *ngFor="let i of data.data">{{ i }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but i really need to have an expression that evaluates to a boolean in my custom component's <my-progress-bar [showProgress]="" > attribute.

Comment: @fumeng, if is under the <ng-container> `[showProgress]="data.data?true:false"`. The use of construction *ngIf="{data:(dataStatus$ | async) } as data" return an object with one property "data" this is undefined or the result of the observable. This is util to not repeat the |async

Comment: thank you, i understand the use of "as data" to prevent the duplicate subscription. but the <my-progress-bar> is not under the container (see my post) -- and i guess that's the problem.

Comment: @fumeng, enclosed all in a new ng-container, then your inner ng-container use `*ngFor='let item of data.data'"` instead `*ngFor='let data of dataStatus$ | async'` (see that it's necesary rename the "data" variable

Answer (score 1):

try this approach:

```
<my-progress-bar [showProgress]='!((dataStatus$ | async) as dataStatus)'>
    <table>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let data of dataStatus'>
            <tr *ngIf='!!data'>
                <td>/* all my stuff */</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
</my-progress-bar>
```

Comment: I like this but it's not quite working. Whatever is in the [showProgress] block is throwing an error. The error says: Parser error: Missing expected )....'. If I simply do [showProgress]='!(dataStatus$ | async)' and keep the async as part of the container ngFor then it works.

Comment: this way getData will be called twice which isn't good. u can use shareReplay operator on your observerable to prevent such case like this:
this.myService.getData()
.pipe(shareReplay())

Comment: Good point. But do you know how to fix your original solution, though? That'd be the best option.

Comment: it's pretty hard for me to debug without having a running sample. it should be pretty close to what I've wrote, try playing with it